# Handling HTTP Query parameters in http-conduit

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I want to download the content of the URL

```
http://example.com/foobar?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

using [*http-conduit*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit) (GET request).

How can I do that:

a) Assuming I already know the full (i.e. encoded URL)
b) If some parameters are dynamic and therefore not URL-encoded?

**Note:** This question was answered Q&A-style and therefore intentionally does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding a):

You can use `simpleHttp` with an URL containing query parameters just like the example in the docs:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB

main :: IO ()
main =
    simpleHttp "http://example.com/foobar?key1=value1&key2=value2" >>= LB.putStr
```

Regarding b):

You need a list of key/value tuples of type `[(ByteString, Maybe ByteString)]` that contains your query parameters.

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB

queryParams :: [(ByteString, Maybe ByteString)]
queryParams = [
    ("key1", Just "value1"),
    ("key2", Just "value2")]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    request <- parseUrl "http://example.com/foobar"
    let request' = setQueryString queryParams request
    response <- withManager $ httpLbs request'
    LB.putStrLn $ responseBody response
```

Note: This requires at least *http-conduit* 2.1.
Also note that it is recommended to reuse `Manager` instances where applicable.