# Download wikipedia markup using Haskell

Tags: haskell, wiki-markup, http-conduit

Using [`http-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit) I want to download the raw wikimedia markup for any page, for example the Wikipedia page `Stack Overflow`.

Also, I'd like the solution to be applicable to wikimedia pages other than `en.wikipedia.org`, for example `de.wikibooks.org`.

**Note:** This question was immediately answered in Q&A form and therefore intentionally does not show research effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question uses query parameters in http-conduits as described [in this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25145343/2597135).

We will use the method described [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22225077/2597135) to download the markup content of a page.

Although this task could be possible using the [mediawiki](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mediawiki), it seems significantly simpler to use the `?action=raw` method without explicitly using the API.

In order to support different pages (e.g. `en.wikimedia.org`), I wrote two functions `getWikipediaPageMarkup` and `getEnwikiPageMarkup`, the former one being more general and allowing to use custom domains (any domain should work, assuming Mediawiki is installed under `/wiki`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
import Network.HTTP.Types (urlEncode)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

-- | Get the Mediawiki marup
getWikipediaPageMarkup :: ByteString -- ^ The wikipedia domain, e.g. "en.wikipedia.org"
                       -> ByteString -- ^ The wikipedia page title to download
                       -> IO LB.ByteString -- ^ The wikipedia page markup
getWikipediaPageMarkup domain page = do
    let url = "https://" <> domain <> "/wiki/" <> urlEncode True page
    request <- parseUrl $ B.unpack url
    let request' = setQueryString [("action", Just "raw")] request
    fmap responseBody $ withManager $ httpLbs request'

-- | Like @getWikipediaPageMarkup@, but hardcoded to 'en.wikipedia.org'
getEnwikiPageMarkup :: ByteString -> IO LB.ByteString
getEnwikiPageMarkup = getWikipediaPageMarkup "en.wikipedia.org"
```

Note that a recent `http-conduit` version is required (minimum: `2.1`, tested with `2.1.4`) in order to compile the code.